# M-x compile and shell-command ignore default-directory

Tags: shell-command, compilation-mode

On one computer I use, my emacs will always run commands in my home directory, rather than the directory of the currently open file (i.e. `default-directory`).

A standalone reproduction is executing the following:

```
(let ((default-directory "/tmp/")) (compile "pwd"))
```

On the computer in question, it prints the path to my home, not `/tmp` as it does on all other computers-with-emacs I have access to. (The same thing happens with `M-!`/`M-x shell-command`.)

I recently installed 24.5 into my user folder (the global install is 23.4), and installed Emacs Prelude but the behaviour described above happened/happens in all configurations (it certainly happened before I made any modifications) and happens if I run `emacs -Q` (for both 24.5 and 23.4) to avoid reading my configurations (as lawlist asks).

If there's no obvious problem/fix, is there a good way to start to debug a problem like this?

Comment: Does it happen when you start Emacs with absolutely no user configuration whatsoever?  `Emacs -Q`  If not, then consider bisecting your user configuration (commenting stuff out) until you find the culprit.

Comment: @lawlist, yes, it does still happen unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like your shell is doing something. What OS are you running? What shell? What happens if you start a new shell in a terminal in a non-default directory? Try running your shell with the `-x` option if it's a typical Unix shell (bash, zsh, tcsh, …).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with overriding `$HOME` and tracking some things through with `bash -x` as @Gilles suggested, I found my `~/.bash_profile` included an isolated `cd` command, meaning the shell emacs spawned to compile/run commands was always left in my home directory.

(Annoying, and apparently my fault, although I have no idea how that `cd` got there.)